# SSRS inserting duplicate query string parameters on Action links

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, query-string

I am working with an SSRS report, and I'm trying to build links to SharePoint list items through an expression on the Action of a Placeholder. The problem that manifests whenever I put any query string values into the link is that SSRS is duplicating them. When SharePoint receives this URL, this causes the New Item page to come up instead of displaying the list item.

Here is the expression where I'm building the link:

```
="http://home.oursharepointsite.net" & Left(First(Fields!Url.Value,"List"),InStrRev(First(Fields!Url.Value, "List"),"/")) & "DispForm.aspx?ID=" & Fields!ListItemId.Value
```

And here is the resulting link:

```
http://home.oursharepointsite.net/communities/home/Sites/CORPFI/Wiki1/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=395&ID=395
```

Another developer I work with isn't using the Action of a Placeholder but rather just building `<a>` tags and gets the same behavior. In his case it doesn't affect the rendering of what he's linking to though.

Does anyone know a way to solve this conundrum?

Comment: Well, I found that if I wrap "javascript: void(window.open(_link here_))" around my link string I was building that it works like it should. I'd still like to know if anyone knows how to solve this problem without this hack though.

Comment: I use similar expressions for links in reports and don't see this. I'm suspicious of the values coming into this or if the SSRS link item has a parameter defined as well as in your expression.

Comment: I've seen this happen too, it works in BIDS but not on the server.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this problem and was able to solve it by making the link relative instead of absolute.
Try dropping the `"http://home.oursharepointsite.net"` and replace it with `"/"`.